# Can the "Laws" listed in Rust trait documentation be enforced?

Tags: rust

The documentation for some Rust traits includes a "Laws" section, e.g. the [documentation](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.1/num/traits/identities/trait.One.html) for `num::traits::identities::One` includes the following:

> Defines a multiplicative identity element for Self.
>
> **Laws**
>
> ```
> a * 1 = a       ∀ a ∈ Self
>
> 1 * a = a       ∀ a ∈ Self
> ```

Does Rust include any mechanism for enforcing these rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to enforce that kind of "laws" in Rust. Yet?